# How to find definite integral of following?

Tags: definite-integrals

> $$ \int_1^2 (2+3t)^{3/2} \ dt
> $$

I dont know how to solve this when $3/2$ is outside the brackets. If somebody could explain to me how to do this in the simplest way possible I would greatly appreciate it!

Comment: Image not available.

Comment: The image is not available.

Comment: my apologies, fixed now.

Comment: Do you know u- substitution?

Answer (score 3):

Set a change of variable $x = 2+3t, \ dx = 3 dt$. This gives the new bound $x\in [5,8]$ :
$$
\int_1^2 (2+3t)^{3/2} \ dt = \frac13\int_5^8 x^{3/2}\ dx
$$
Can you conclude using the well-known "$x^n$" primitive ?